# Error when deploying SSIS package to azure

Tags: azure, deployment, ssis

Deploy SSIS package to azure fails on validation from both vs2019 and SSMS environments.

**VS2019**: "Package deployment is not supported for SSIS in Azure Data Factory"

**SSMS**: "Package": Connection '....' contains host name.

(my package contains ADO.NET connection manager with server name that points to an azure sql server ****.database.windows.net)

Any suggestions?

[image: ssms]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to MS documentation - [Validate packages deployed to Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/lift-shift/ssis-azure-validate-packages?view=sql-server-ver15)

> - **Host name**. If a server property contains host name instead of IP address, validation raises a warning. Packages that contain host
>     name may fail, typically because the Azure virtual network requires
>     the correct DNS configuration to support DNS name resolution.

and the - [Deploy and run packages in Azure lift and shift](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/lift-shift/ssis-azure-lift-shift-ssis-packages-overview?view=sql-server-ver15)

> **Deploy projects and packages** - You have to use the project deployment model, not the package
>   deployment model, when you deploy projects to SSISDB on Azure.

Comment: The second was my issue.  I was trying to deploy packages that I had previously deployed, but I did it at a package level, not a project level.  Thanks for the quick fix!